# Naked domain with Openshift

Tags: dns, openshift

One of the biggest issue I have faced with GAE cloud offering from Google is that it cannot handle naked domains.

It can handle subdomains www however not naked domains. This is a BIG problem, in that your app will not be able to handle PATH or Subdirectory from client request as it is stripped off during a DNS forward to a www subdomain for example.

So my question is, can Openshift handle naked domains? In that, a PATH or Subdirectory from client request would not be lost in translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember DNS A-Records require a static IP address and Openshift online currently does not have the ability to assign a static IP to an app.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was to add DNS record

**Hostname**: *
**Type**: CNAME
**Value**: {*my_web*}.rhcloud.com

(did it in my domain console from iwantmyname)