# How to use naked GoDaddy domain with OpenShift hosting?

Tags: openshift, domain-name

**Desired Behaviour**

I have a GoDaddy domain name and am using OpenShift for hosting.

I would like the following to be true:

a) user enters `www.mysitename.com` > user sees `mysitename.com`

b) user enters `www.mysitename.com/about.html` > user sees `mysitename.com/about.html`

c) user enters `mysitename.com` or `mysitename.com/about.html` and they also see that url.

d) to summarise, the `www` prefix is never displayed anywhere on the site.

**Constraints**

OpenShift hosting does not have a static IP, so it is not possible to adjust the `A record` at GoDaddy.

The format for the OpenShift app is `http://appname-username.rhcloud.com`.

You can set up a cname at GoDaddy with the following:

`www > appname-username.rhcloud.com`

This means the site is accessible at `www.mydomain.com` but not at `mydomain.com`.

**Suggested Solutions**

There are several posts on the topic that suggest the following but for several reasons are not adequate solutions:

- [use a subdomain](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way) ie `blog.mydomain.com`
- [use wwwizer](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/problem-with-forwarding-and-addresses#comment-31766)
- [use forwarding and masking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21809900/1063287) (causes the url to stay the same when navigating relative links)

**Question**

Can anyone think of another solution that satisfies the desired behaviour stated above?

Or do I need to change to a registrar that allows "naked cname records"?

**Related Posts**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431034/godaddy-domain-pointing-to-openshift-hosting
[Naked domain with Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946880/naked-domain-with-openshift)
[How do I add an alias for a naked domain with OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045151/how-do-i-add-an-alias-for-a-naked-domain-with-openshift)

**Edit**

This blog posts sums up the scenario:

http://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp

Could I sign up for CloudFlare to resolve the issue?

I haven't used it before and don't know how it works.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Solution**

**01)**  [Sign up to cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/sign-up)
**02)**  Set these cname rules:

`mydomain.com > appname-username.rhcloud.com` (this will utilise '[cname flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)')

`www > mydomain.com`

**03)**  Set page rules:

`http://www.mydomain.com/* > http://mydomain.com/$1`

**04)**  Set alias in OpenShift to `mydomain.com`

**05)**  Make sure GoDaddy DNS record doesn't have any conflicting `cname` or `A record` set up.

**06)**  Let it simmer overnight and all of the original desired behaviour should be working.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what would be a conflicting cname or A record? The only record I have at the moment is this cname rule: `www > blabla-blablabla.rhcloud.com`. Since I bought my domain from GoDaddy I suppose I still need to have a rue setup over there. Is it ok like this or should it look different?

Comment: Yes. That works. Check for the page rules. That makes every thing works. select forwarding in the select box in cloudflare

Comment: I followed these steps and now it's redirecting to 'https' and '/app' on my rhcloud url. Any hint?

Comment: @Azghanvi use set the alias in web console of opeshift to www.domain.com

Answer (score 26):

Here is what worked for me.

```
Domain name : example.com
openshift app: myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com

--on godaddy
      Domains>All Domains>select your domain example.com>click DNS ZONE FILE tab
      1. delete www CNAME
      2. create new Record with 
         Record Type CNAME > HOST: www > POINT TO: myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com
      3. click Finish 

      Click Settings tab
      1. Forwarding > click Manage
         Forward to:www.example.com > Redirect: 301 (Permanent) > Type: Forward only
      2. click ADD

--on Openshift
      1. select Application tab > select application myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com        
         > click change
      2. enter Domain name www.example.com
```

That's it. Wait for 10-15 min and see the magic.

Comment: It is forwarding to https://www.example/com/app 
i) https was not there
ii) /app is incorrect

Any hint to resolve it?

Comment: @Azghanvi use www.example.com with www in alias in openshift web console

Comment: It does not get rid of the 'www' but provides an easy workaround. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, needed exactly this!!!! thank you!!!

Answer (score 7):

To get your domain (with 'www' and without), to successfully point to your OpenShift alias, without 'masking' or 'forwarding' see this tutorial I wrote:

- [How to get a custom domain and naked domains work for your OpenShift application](http://sirwan.me/how-to-get-custom-domains-and-naked-domains-to-work-with-your-openshift-application/)

It works with CNAME Flattening.

Comment: Ugh.  Dead link:  Error 1001 Ray ID: 241659d5a94e11a1 • 2015-11-07 04:38:50 UTC

Comment: I have just edited my answer with a correct working link. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

@Azghanvi: I faced the same problem.
Make sure you add "www.example.com" as your alias in openshift and not "example.com".
Seems like Godaddy does not support "example.com" by default.